# How to prove that every (finite) tree contains at least one vertex with degree 1 in Lean?

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorics, lean

How to prove that every (finite) tree contains at least one vertex with degree 1 in Lean?

I'm currently using the combinatorics.simple_graph.connectivity import.

I've defined a vertex of degree one as

```
def vertex_degree_one (v : V) :=
  ∃! (u : V), u ≠ v ∧ G.adj v u
```

And the formalization of the lemma that I'm attempting to prove is

```
lemma tree_exists_vertexDegreeOne (v : V) (hg : G.is_tree) (hfin : fintype G.support) (vertices : v ∈ G.support)
          : (∃ w ∈ G.support, @vertex_degree_one V G w) := --where w is that vertex with degree 1
```

Note that G.support is the set of vertices that form edges in G, and that it is defined as a finite type.

The proof is by contradiction, so we assume that every vertex has degree of at least 2. So we start at a vertex v_0, and since it has degree >=2, we can go to v_1. Similarly, we can walk to v_2 where v_2 != v_0. Note that v_{i-1] != v_{i+1}. This path must be finite, meaning that at some point we would have to loop around to v_1, which creates a cycle, leading to our contradiction.

The problem I have here is that I'm pretty stuck on how to define this "walk", in which we have a finite path and must eventually loop around to the beginning, thus creating a cycle. There isn't much information on graph theory in Lean so I was wondering if anyone could give me some pointers on how to approach this.

Comment: I'd make a lemma about what happens if something is in the support and `¬vertex_degree_one`; you can then try to create this list of vertices, and with some (admittedly semi-painful-looking) rejigging, you should be able to create a `simple_graph.walk.is_cycle`, or maybe a `trail`, eventually.  You'll want to have some of the pigeonhole principle results; you should be able to find them using `pigeonhole` in the docs search.

Comment: Do you need an answer expressed in lean, or can you take a regular math proof and do the translation yourself? If the latter, note that if every vertex has degree >= 2 then the graph must have a cycle b/c any vertex you visit you can also leave, so it isn't a tree. If the graph is finite.

Answer (score 0):

How about a proof by induction on the size of the support of the graph? First, prove that adjoining a vertex to a tree, where on adjoining, it is connected to a single vertex on the tree, creates a tree. Then, prove that connecting the adjoining vertex without connecting isn't a tree, because it's disconnected, and to two vertices isn't a tree, because by the tree property, you have a path between the two vertices, and your new vertex now creates a cycle. Necessarily, if adjoining, the new vertex must be of degree one.

Now, by inducting on the size of the support, you can show that every finite graph that is a tree is constructable by this process. The base case of a tree is C_2, which has a vertex of degree one, by inspection. In the inductive case, your new vertex is degree one by construction.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways of proving this, depending on how you define a tree, or what facts you have available at the start.

E.g., if you start knowing that a tree on n vertices is connected and has n-1 edges then you're done. Each edge contributes 2 to the sum of the degrees, so the total sum of degrees is 2(n-1). But if each of n vertices had degree at least 2 then the total sum of degrees would be 2n. Contradiction.

Alternatively, you could prove this by contradiction. Let T be such a tree and v be some vertex in T. Start a random walk in T from v, going from neighbor to unvisited neighbor. You're guaranteed to hit some vertex for the second time before you have to stop, because every vertex you reach has at least one edge you haven't used yet. Call the first such vertex you find w. Now you have a proof by contradiction in two ways: 1) More than one path between a pair of vertices in a tree, or 2) a cycle in a tree.